# Is it possible to thank Stack Overflow without writing it as a question?

Tags: discussion, meta, thanks

I would like to thank all of Stack Overflow for already having solutions to so many of my problems that I almost never have to post a question.

Answer (score 10):

You can do so by voting on the answers that helped you.

You already earned the privilege to vote on Science Fiction & Fantasy. You only need [15 points on most sites](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up), easily earned with some good quality suggested edits, for example.